# Can't override virtual function using SFINAE (std::enable_if)

Tags: c++11, virtual, sfinae

The code below overrides `virtual A::foo()` with `B::foo() override`.  If the `BROKEN` is not defined, then it compiles just fine. My understanding of the `std::enable<std::is_pod<Q>::value>::type` shenanigans is that it effectively replaces the SFINAE expression with `void`, and this should be identical to plain old `void`.

However, it won't compile. I get compiler errors:

#### Intel compiler (icpc):

```
$ make a CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -DBROKEN"
icpc -std=c++11 -DBROKEN    a.cpp   -o a
a.cpp(24): error: object of abstract class type "B<int>" is not allowed:
            pure virtual function "A::foo" has no overrider
     B<int> b;
            ^
```

#### gcc:

```
$ make a CXXFLAGS="-std=c++11 -DBROKEN" CXX=g++
g++ -std=c++11 -DBROKEN    a.cpp   -o a
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:24:11: error: cannot declare variable ‘b’ to be of abstract type ‘B<int>’
    B<int> b;
           ^
a.cpp:9:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘B<int>’:
 class B : A
       ^
a.cpp:5:16: note:       virtual void A::foo()
   virtual void foo() = 0;
                ^
make: *** [a] Error 1
```

Here is the test case:

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {
  public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class B : A
{
  public:

#ifdef BROKEN
  template<class Q = T>
  typename std::enable_if<true>::type
#else
  void
#endif
  foo() override { }
};

int main()
{
   B<int> b;
   b.foo();
   return 0;
}
```

If I don't use virtual functions, the `std::enable<true>` thing works as expected.

### addendum

Those results were for gcc 4.8.3. With gcc 5.3, I get one extra line of compiler error:

```
a.cpp:19:9: error: member template ‘std::enable_if<true>::type B<T>::foo()’ may not have virt-specifiers
   foo() override { }

     ^
```

Why not?

Answer (score 6):

This is not pretty, but it got the job done... virtual override with a SFINAE conditional compilation. It has more call overhead (`foo()` calls `foo_x()`), but maybe the compiler will optimize that out.

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {
  public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class B : A
{
  public:

  template<class Q = T>
  typename std::enable_if<true>::type
  foo_x() { }

  void foo() override { foo_x(); }
};

int main()
{
   B<int> b;
   b.foo(); // not an example of polymorphism! just want it to compile.
   return 0;
}
```

That example is merely to prove that it compiles and is useless. The actual implementations of `foo_x` will have multiple implementations:

```
  template<class Q = T>
  typename std::enable_if<is_pod<Q>::value>::type
  foo_x() { /* do something with POD */}

  template<class Q = T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<std::string,Q>::value>::type
  foo_x() { /* do something with a std::string */}

  template<class Q = T>
  typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<MyCrazyClass,Q>::value>::type
  foo_x() { /* do something with a derived class of MyCrazyClass */}
```

Comment: Forget my prior comment, I missed the point of this. Just to make it clear to other readers, you'd have multiple `foo_x` methods, each with `enable_if`, so that for each `T`, exactly one would be enabled, right?